# How to predict a linear model with lags?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, forecasting, economics

I am sorry if this question is too simple. I tried to find something similar here, but the "semi" related questions were too complex to my current knowledge.

I want to predict a linear model with lags. I wrote the following code:

```
mod.lm <- dynlm::dynlm(diff(log(pib.nsa)) ~ stats::lag(diff(log(pib.nsa)),-1) + 
                     stats::lag(diff(log(pib.nsa)),-4) + 
                     stats::lag(sel.modelo,-1)+ 
                     stats::lag(sel.modelo,-2)+ 
                     stats::lag(sel.modelo,-3)+ 
                     stats::lag(sel.modelo,-4) + 
                     Qdummies, data = dados)
summary(mod.lm)

fcst <- predict.lm(mod.lm, newdata = newdata))
summary(fcst)
```

`Qdummies` is quarterly seasonal dummies. `dados` is a ts data frame with my dependent (GDP) and independent (interest rate -- sel.modelo) variables, plus the dummies. `new data` is a subset of the former, that has 6 new data points..

The forecasting part does not work. I faced this issue several times, and can't understand why it does not work.

Thank you very much for your time!

**Code to get the data (reproducible example):**

```
library(rbcb)

pib.nsa <- ts(rbcb::get_series(22099, start_date = "1996-03-31", end_date = "2019-06-01")$'22099',
      start = c(1996,1), freq = 4)

Selic_fonte <- rbcb::get_series(1178, start_date="1996-01-02", end_date = "2019-09-30")
  colnames(Selic_fonte) <- c("date", "selic")  

Selic_3m <- Selic_fonte %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Data = Selic_fonte$date) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Quarter = lubridate::quarter(Data, with_year = T)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Quarter) %>%
  dplyr::select(Quarter, selic) 

Selic_3m <- dplyr::summarise_at(Selic_3m, vars(selic), funs(mean))
Selic_3m <- ts(Selic_3m$selic, start=c(1996,01), freq=4)


Selic_proj <- ts(c(4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4), frequency = 4, start = c(2019,4))

Selic_exog <- ts(c(Selic_3m, Selic_proj), start=c(1996,01), freq=4)

sel.modelo <- window(Selic_exog, end = end(pib.nsa))
sel.novo <- tail(Selic_exog)

Qdummies <- ts(seasonaldummy(data), start = start(dados), frequency = 4) 

sel.modelo <- window(Selic, end = end(pib.nsa))
sel.novo <- tail(Selic)

dados <- ts.intersect(pib.nsa, sel.modelo, Qdummies)
newdata <- ts.intersect(sel.novo, Qdummies)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? I need to have some sample data so I can run your code too

Comment: @Edo I am sorry about that. Just added the code I used to get the data. Since I upload straight from the web, you can use the same data! Thank you for your helpfullness!

Comment: Haven’t tried your code yet.. though I can tell you that dynlm uses its own functions to lag and diff: L and d. Check out help(dynlm)